# Ionic 3 Keyboard pushes background image

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing an Ionic 3 android application.

I faced a problem where keyboard hides text inputs and I fixed that with adding the following line inside `config.xml`

```
<preference name="resizeOnFullScreen" value="true" />
```

But this fix created an other problem which is in my login page, the keyboard pushes the background image and change its position

[image]

Here is the code

```
.imageBackground {
   background: url("../assets/img/bckgLogin.png") no-repeat center center fixed !important;
   background-size: cover !important;
   -webkit-background-size:cover !important;
   background-attachment: fixed !important;
   background-position-x: -340px !important;
 }
```

Is there any fix for this guys ?

Comment: Try: `ion-content{
  --background: url('../../assets/img/imageName.png') 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
}`

Comment: on keyboard open give some sort of height to your container or ion-content & remove that height ok keyboard close make that scrollable

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I already tried that with no luck

Comment: @KrunalVaghela I already though of that, but I question if there is a more simple way